# Wrong count git commits

Tags: git, bash, git-merge

I have a small bash script:

```
echo "Total commits: "
git log --all --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --date=short | wc -l
echo "Total no-merge commits: "
git log --all --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --date=short --no-merges | wc -l
echo "Total merge commits: "
git log --all --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --date=short --merges | wc -l
```

I know that the code is not optimal.
The Result of my script:

```
Total commits:  
1000
Total no-merge commits:  
817
Total merge commits: 
182
```

**Question:** why is the sum of no-merge and merge commits (182+817 = 999) lower than the total commits (1000)?

Comment: What happens if you `for x in --merges --no-merges ""; do git rev-list --count $x --all; done` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output from those log commands uses `\n` as a separator, not a terminator, so your `wc -l` counts are all one short. You really have:

```
1001 = 818 + 183
```

commits, which adds up.

From `git help log`:

> The `tformat:` format works exactly like `format:`, except that it
>   provides "terminator" semantics instead of "separator" semantics.
>   In other words, each commit has the message terminator character
>   (usually a newline) appended, rather than a separator placed
>   between entries. This means that the final entry of a single-line
>   format will be properly terminated with a new line, just as the
>   "oneline" format does.